# Sending multiple DocuSign Template in one email?

Tags: php, rest, docusignapi

How can I do this in DocuSign? Currently what I'm doing is sending each template individually to the assignee using DocuSign's REST API and following this [example](https://github.com/Ergin008/DocuSign-REST-API-Webinar-April2013/blob/master/example2.php)

Would this be possible using their REST API? Also, I was thinking of turning the `$data` variable into an array that contains all the necessary information needed for the template to be sent, if that is even possible.

Comment: Please paste your code where you want to need help.

Comment: @RohitSuthar That's the problem I only know how to send individual templates and don't have any code or guide for multiple templates in one email. I was hoping someone could direct me to the right direction.

Comment: then you're at wrong place. here you can't ask the suggestions. so first implement for ideas in your code and ask for the errors, how to resolve it???

Comment: I am asking for the communities opinion regarding this matter since I don't know how to implement this, if I knew how I wouldn't be here asking, And there are a lot of questions here is SO that are asking for opinions on how to proceed on certain matters, and you saying it doesn't is just being ignorant, If you don't know anything about DocuSign then just stay quiet as I would appreciate it more if you are helpful just than spewing negativity.

Comment: so you just need opinion??

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please upvote all useful answers, including those to others' questions. And please "check" (accept) the best answer to your own questions. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To place more than one template in a DocuSign envelope, you need to use the Composite Template structure in your call.  In short, each template would live in a composite template.  In each composite template, you would identify your server template, and you would use the inline template to define recipients and any data you are trying to merge into the template.

Here is some json I use in Runscope/Postman.

```
{
  "emailSubject": "DocuSign Widget Order and NDA",
  "emailBlurb": "Please let us know if you have any questions.",
  "status": "sent",
  "compositeTemplates": [
    {
      "serverTemplates": [
        {
          "sequence": "1",
          "templateId": "templateIDremoved"
        }
      ],
      "inlineTemplates": [
        {
          "sequence": "1",
          "recipients": {
            "signers": [
              {
                "email": "signerrob@outlook.com",
                "name": "Customer Bob",
                "roleName": "Customer",
                "recipientId": "1",
                "tabs": {
                  "textTabs": [
                    {
                      "tabLabel": "company",
                      "value": "ABC Corporation"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              },
              {
                "email": "senderrob@outlook.com",
                "name": "Sender Rob",
                "recipientId": "2",
                "roleName": "Legal"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "serverTemplates": [
        {
          "sequence": "2",
          "templateId": "templateIDremoved"
        }
      ],
      "inlineTemplates": [
        {
          "sequence": "2",
          "recipients": {
            "signers": [
              {
                "email": "signerrob@outlook.com",
                "name": "Customer Bob",
                "recipientId": "1",
                "roleName": "Customer"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```